# How can I place an IR cut filter on an M12 lens?

Tags: lens, filters, lens-mount, infrared

I have an M12 lens and my camera doesn't have an IR cut filter. It's difficult to find an IR cut lens for my specific sensor size and desired focal length (sensor size 1/2.3, focal 2-4mm). Is there a way to stick an IR cut filter film(?) behind a regular M12 lens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optical filters be they IR, UV, ND, or colored, can usually be mounted anywhere in an optical system. Most are available as dyed glass, or a sandwich of clear glass with a gel (gelatin) filter in the center. You can also buy uncut gelatin filters which you can cut with scissors. Gelatin filters are high quality optical flats. They can be hand-held before the lens or mounted between lens elements or mounted behind the lens. You can buy or make a filter holder. If you are handy, you will figure out how to mount a gel. You can even use adhesive tape to temporarily hold them in place.